# Sorting Datagridview's Column by text and not value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a column in my datagridview that is a combobox column. I would like it sorted by it's display value (i.e. text) instead of it's value (in this case, a list of int's from the database).

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you include code to show how you are currently filling your comboBox?

Comment: It's being filled from datasets

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by overriding the `SortCompare` event on the `DataGridView` which:

> Occurs when the DataGridView compares two cell values to perform a sort operation

and having it always sort on the Display Value instead of the Default Value.

1. Wire up the [`SortCompare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare.aspx) event to the DataGridView like this:

```cs
this.dataGridView1.SortCompare += new DataGridViewSortCompareEventHandler(dataGridView1_SortCompare);
```

2. Then add the event handler to sort all columns by each [`Cell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx)'s  [`FormattedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue.aspx) property rather than the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) property (which is the default).

```cs
void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = (DataGridView) sender
    string value1 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex1].Cells[e.Column.Index].FormattedValue.ToString();
    string value2 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex2].Cells[e.Column.Index].FormattedValue.ToString();

    e.SortResult = System.String.Compare(value1, value2);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Works for me, and will hopefully help other people out.  I just wish there was a setting on the `DataGridView` to make this the default option.

Comment: This event appears not to fire for me!

Comment: "This event occurs only when the DataSource property is not set and the VirtualMode property value is false." - turns out its no use if the D ataGridView is bound! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Its not impossible to do this at all. This is how I've done it.

What you need to create a virtual column that is filled with the bound value. You will need to programatically do this.

```
private void OrderByComboBoxColumn()
{
// Add the temp Column if it doesnt exist
if (!dataset.TABLE.Columns.Contains("TempColumn"))
    dataset.TABLE.Columns.Add("TempColumn", typeof(string));

foreach (DataSetRow row in dataset.TABLE)
    row["TempColumn"] = GetBoundValue(row.COMBOBOX_ID);

dataview.Sort = "TempColumn ASC";

}

private string GetBoundValue(int id)
{
// get the string however your id matches the bound value
return string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [How to: Customize Sorting in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx).  There are three different ways to sort in that article.  A couple of other posts that might help out as well: [How to sort databound datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699642/how-to-sort-databound-datagridview-column) and [Custom sort of datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435177/c-custom-sort-of-datagridview)

Comment: That event never happens, I've already tried that way and it didn't work.

Comment: The SortCompare event doesn't occur when the DataGridView is databound. From MSDN : "This event occurs only when the DataSource property is not set and the VirtualMode property value is false."

Answer (score 1):

As [mnield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109030/mnield) pointed out, the above code will not work  if we have `ComboBox` column and the user wants to be able to add rows.

If user wants to be able to add new rows then we should use the following code:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) dataGridView1.Columns[1];
col.DataSource = items;
col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) dataGridView1.Columns[1];
col.DataSource = items;
col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
```

This code only allows sorting by ID not by the Text of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is not possible.  I was looking for the same thing and I am not sure why no one would have thought this was an important feature.  Here is the link to the original question and the answer from a Microsoft Rep.

http://www.webnewsgroups.net/vbnet/t25706-vb2005-sort-datagridview-text-formattedvalue-combobox-column-instead-underlying-value.aspx

> Hi Matt,
>
> Thank you for posting.
>
> If you have a
>   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in your
>   DataGridView, you have to set the
>   DataSource of the DataGridView to
>   populate data in it. That's to say,
>   you must bind the DataGridView to a
>   datasource.
>
> If you set the SortMode of the
>   DataGridViewComoboBoxColumn to
>   Automatic, you can sort this column by
>   clicking it. The sorting is based on
>   the cells' value in the column, not
>   the FormattedValue. If you want to
>   sort this column based on the
>   FormattedValue, it seems that you have
>   to customize the sorting.
>
> There're several options for custom
>   sort of DataGridView. These options
>   are listed below.
>   1. Calling DataGridView.Sort(DataGridViewColumn,ListSortDirection)
>   method
>   2. Handling with the DataGridView's SortCompare event
>   3. Calling DataGridView.Sort(IComparer) method
>
> You can refer to the below link for
>   more information on the above three
>   options:
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608(d=ide).aspx
>
> 1. Using DataView and set the its Sort property
>
> You can refer to he below link for
>   more information on the option4:
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort(d=ide).as
>   px
>
> It seems that only option2 and option3
>   could be applied to sort the
>   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn based on
>   the FormattedValue. However, these two
>   options only apply under the condition
>   that the DataGridView is NOT bounded
>   to a DataSource.
>
> So in my opinion, it is impossible to
>   sort a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
>   based on the FormattedValue.
>
> If you have other concerns, please
>   don't hesitate to let me know.
>
> Sincerely, Linda Liu Microsoft Online
>   Community Support

Answer (score 0):

In fact is quite simple, this is a sample code that worked for me:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) dataGridView1.Columns[1];
col.DataSource = items;
col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
```

The third line is the key.