# Sort ComboboxColumn in DataGridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

There DataGridView, the source - the table in the database, implemented in DataGridView column type ComboboxColumn related to another table in the database to display correctly connected data.

Question: when sorting staff to DataGridview means that clicking on the column header, sorting is conducted by ValueMember ComboboxColumn. How to change the sort order that it was made based on DisplayMember?

Comment: Could you perhaps update ValueMember to match DisplayMember?

Comment: Unfortunately no in ValueMember i used the Id values that used in other place

Comment: Can the DataGridView be sorted programmatically, or do you only want it to sort when you click the column headers?

Comment: programmatically in terms of using SortCompare event? The fact that this event will not fire on binding DataGridView

Comment: Perhaps one of these two questions could hold the answer for you. [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044893/sorting-datagridviews-column-by-text-and-not-value)  [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386882/sorting-datagridview-by-column-displaymember)

Comment: JP's 2nd link is a good one, imo..

Comment: Sorting happened by value of column in your database bounded to datagridview in the comboboxcolumn (See `ComboboxColumn.DataProperty`)