# VB.net: Comparing IP Addresses Strings for sorting in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, ip-address

I have a datagridview with a string column of IP addresses of devices that are found dynamically.

**Problem:** I want to compare this string of IP addresses so that I can sort them as an IP address and not as a string. I took some hints from stackflow questions [C#: Custom sort of DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435177/c-custom-sort-of-datagridview) and see that you basically have to sort the original datasource, and then display it on the datagridview.

**What I have tried:**

I tried creating an IComparer class, but I got a InvalidOperation exception that said creating a new comparer is not good since it is a databound object. So, that's out of the question. What I want to know is a good string algorithm to basically redo this so that 10.10.1.190 goes before 10.10.1.199.

My first thinking was to remove the ".", multiply, and do a number comparer, but that doesn't work with a large middle number (i.e. 10.10.0.197 versus 10.10.1.2).

I also tried creating a list of Ipaddresses (direct parse from the datagridview's cells) but the list.sort() function errors out as well.

Here's the code I have inside the header click event (when I want it to sort):

```
      If selectedColumn.Name = "IP Address" Then
         'gives error, invalidOperation
       'cameraTable is the datagridview name
       '   cameraTable.Sort(New CellComparer(SortOrder.Ascending))

            For i As Integer = 0 To cameraTable.Rows.Count - 1
                unsortedCopy.Add(Net.IPAddress.Parse(cameraTable("IP Address", i).Value.ToString))

           Next

           'gives error
            unsortedCopy.Sort()

        'make new datatable with sorting matching array 
        'make it datasource
        'refresh GUI

        End If
```

What's a a good way to compare IP addresses? Or possibly making the custom sorting in a more elegant way?

Comment: This could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248039/how-to-sort-list-of-ip-addresses-using-c-sharp

Comment: You might need to use a DataTable as the source for your DataGridView. That way you can use Steve's suggestion to convert the IPv4 dotted-notation to a UInt32 and sort on that. You don't have to actually display the column with the UInt32 value.

Comment: I'm changing my code to copying over the column and putting it into an array of String() that has it split by ".". I'm going to try and see if vb.net will let me follow steve's suggestion.

Comment: I'm trying this line.Any tips on how to fix the vb.net complaining of "Version.Parse"? `Dim sortedIps = unsortedIps.[Select](Version.Parse).OrderBy(Function(arg) arg).[Select](Function(arg) arg.ToString()).ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I ended up using:

I created an Icomparer:

```
Class IPAddressComparer
Implements IComparer(Of Net.IPAddress)


Public Function Compare1(x As Net.IPAddress, y As Net.IPAddress) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of Net.IPAddress).Compare
    Dim first As Byte() = x.GetAddressBytes()
    Dim second As Byte() = y.GetAddressBytes()
    Return first.Zip(second, Function(a, b) a.CompareTo(b)).FirstOrDefault(Function(c) c <> 0)
End Function
End Class
```

Then I made an array of the IPAddresses as strings, and sorted it using that:

```
  Dim unsortedCopy As New List(Of String)

            For i As Integer = 0 To cameraTable.Rows.Count - 1
                unsortedCopy.Add(cameraTable(selectedColumn.Name, i).Value.ToString)
            Next

            Dim sorted = unsortedCopy.OrderBy(Function(s) Net.IPAddress.Parse(s), New IPAddressComparer())
```

This created a string array with the addresses in order. Worked pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

Heres a comparer class to sort by IP address in a datagridview.

```
Public Class RowComparer
    Implements System.Collections.IComparer
    Private sortOrderModifier As Integer = 1

    Public Sub New(ByVal sortOrder As SortOrder)
        If sortOrder = sortOrder.Descending Then
            sortOrderModifier = -1
        ElseIf sortOrder = sortOrder.Ascending Then
            sortOrderModifier = 1
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare

        Dim first As Byte() = IPAddress.Parse(CType(x, DataGridViewRow).Cells(0).Value.ToString()).GetAddressBytes()
        Dim second As Byte() = IPAddress.Parse(CType(y, DataGridViewRow).Cells(0).Value.ToString()).GetAddressBytes()

        'first part of the IP Address
        Dim ipCompare As Integer = If(CInt(first(0)) > CInt(second(0)), 1, If(CInt(first(0)) < CInt(second(0)), -1, 0))
        'second part of the IP Address
        If ipCompare = 0 Then
            ipCompare = If(CInt(first(1)) > CInt(second(1)), 1, If(CInt(first(1)) < CInt(second(1)), -1, 0))
        End If
        'third part of the IP Address
        If ipCompare = 0 Then
            ipCompare = If(CInt(first(2)) > CInt(second(2)), 1, If(CInt(first(2)) < CInt(second(2)), -1, 0))
        End If
        'fourth part of the IP Address
        If ipCompare = 0 Then
            ipCompare = If(CInt(first(3)) > CInt(second(3)), 1, If(CInt(first(3)) < CInt(second(3)), -1, 0))
        End If
        Return ipCompare * sortOrderModifier

    End Function
End Class
```

You handle it as usual, i.e within a button click it would be:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        DataGridView1.Sort(New RowComparer(SortOrder.Ascending))
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        DataGridView1.Sort(New RowComparer(SortOrder.Descending))
    End If 
End Sub
```

PS. The assumption in the class is that the IP address is in the first column (change to suit!).