# Difficulty sorting DataGridView ASP.NET/MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, datagrid

I have a DataGridView which uses template fields and bound Item templates and because of this manual data-bind implementation I am having difficulty finding a way to sort the data by column (Asc,Des).

Could someone provide an example of how to implement this or point our where I'm going wrong.

Example template fields:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User ID">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Binding data code:

```
private void BindData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(conString))
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT UserID,firstname,surname,department,email,username,role,lastlogin,pwordreset FROM users", cn);
        adp.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            usersGridView.DataSource = dt;
            usersGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
```

Sorting function to be called when using dropdown list:

```
private void sortGV(string value)
{
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    DataView dv;

    string sql = "SELECT UserID,firstname,surname,department,email,username,role,lastlogin,pwordreset FROM users";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

    //Fill dataset
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
    dv.Sort = value;

    usersGridView.DataSource = dv;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: in your `sortGV` method what is the value of `value being passed in` you are aware of the `DataView.Filter` property if you have a datatable you would do something like this
`dv.RowFilter = "firstname LIKE '%" + value + "%'";` for example then you would still need to do `usersGridView.DataBind()` after `userGridView.DataSource = dv` keep in mind this will not sort it will filter so you need to add an `Order By` in the select query also the GridView should have some sorting attributes that you can add to the template as well for the sorting when clicking on the column

Comment: do a simple google search on `DataGridView.Sort` and look at this previous posting if you want to use a helper class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435177/c-custom-sort-of-datagridview