# Windows Forms DataGridView C#: Sort Data by Tag Names and Value Names

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have been banging my head trying to get this figured out, scouring the stack-overflow website, but I can't seem to do what I want.

Basically, I have a `DataGridView` on a windows form that I want to sort column 0 by value names, but also by tag names. I have created a simple bit of code to help demonstrate my issue.

The first part in my form that I populate the datagridview with values

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(11);
    //column 1
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "0 - TITLE";
    dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "1";
    dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = "2";
    dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = "3";
    dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[0].Value = "4";
    dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[0].Value = "5";
    dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[0].Value = "6";
    dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[0].Value = "7";
    dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[0].Value = "8";
    dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[0].Value = "9";
    dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[0].Value = "10";


    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Tag = "TITLE";
    dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Tag = "PASS";
    dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Tag = "PASS";
    dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[0].Tag = "FAIL";
    dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[0].Tag = "PASS";
    dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[0].Tag = "PASS";
    dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[0].Tag = "PASS";
    dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[0].Tag = "PASS";
    dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[0].Tag = "FAIL";
    dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[0].Tag = "PASS";
    dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[0].Tag = "PASS";
    //column 2
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "A - TITLE";
    dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = "B - THIS IS";
    dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = "C - A";
    dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value = "D - TEST";
    dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Value = "E - THAT";
    dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Value = "F - I";
    dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value = "G - AM";
    dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[1].Value = "H - RUNNING";
    dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[1].Value = "I - RIGHT";
    dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[1].Value = "J - NOW";
    dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[1].Value = "K - !";
    //column 3
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = "0 - TITLE";
    dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value = "14.999999999999";
    dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[2].Value = "15.0001";
    dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[2].Value = "15.00";
    dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[2].Value = "15.0";
    dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[2].Value = "15";
    dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[2].Value = "11.99";
    dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[2].Value = "12.01";
    dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[2].Value = "12";
    dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[2].Value = "88.65";
    dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[2].Value = "33.25";

}
```

The second part is a button click trigger event, where the sorting is triggered.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn newColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
    DataGridViewColumn oldColumn = dataGridView1.SortedColumn;
    ListSortDirection direction;

    // If oldColumn is null, then the DataGridView is not sorted.
    if (oldColumn != null)
    {
        // Sort the same column again, reversing the SortOrder.
        if (oldColumn == newColumn &&
            dataGridView1.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
        }
        else
        {
            // Sort a new column and remove the old SortGlyph.
            direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            oldColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    }

    // Sort the selected column.
    dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn, direction);
    newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection =
        direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ?
        SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
}
```

So, this code can sort column 0 by value names (both ascending and descending), but when I click the button again I want to be able to sort by the tag names, and in a specific order, meaning title first, followed by fail, followed by pass.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You can sort your data source, for example the `DataTable` or `List<T>` which contains the data.

Comment: Looks like he doesn't have one. The 2nd an 3rd answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435177/c-custom-sort-of-datagridview) are about writing a custom sort for a DGV. But creating and using a DataSource may be simpler, although the custom one might be more flexible..

Answer (score 1):

Since your DGV doesn't have a `DataSource` you will have to write a **Custom Sort**.

This is actually rather simple; it is probably harder to write the logic to switch among the various sorts you want to provide.

First prepare all columns you want to be sortable:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
```

Use your column names!

Next you code the [`SortCompare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. Here is a simple example, sorting by length of the `value.ToString` representation:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    var v1 = e.CellValue1.ToString().Length;
    var v2 = e.CellValue2.ToString().Length;
    e.SortResult = v1 < v2 ? -1 : v1 == v2 ? 0 : 1;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

As you can see you need to set the `e.SortResult` to either `-1, 0 or 1`, meaning `less, equal and greater`. And you set the `e.Handled`param to `true`.

That is all.

For accessing the `Tag` data you can use code like this:

```
 var v1 = dataGridView1[e.Column.Index, e.RowIndex1].Tag.ToString();
```

etc..

Of course, since you have access to all data you can write much more complex code, processing the cell data in any way you want even accessing data from other columns..

Do look into the parameters the [`DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewsortcompareeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) !

To swich your sort modes you can store the current one, increment it, maybe  in the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event and test in the `SortCompare` code..

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a handler to [`DataGridView.SortCompare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare(v=vs.110).aspx) event before calling the `Sort` method and apply your logic there.

For instance:

```
static readonly Dictionary<string, int> sortOrder = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "TITLE", 0 },
    { "FAIL", 1 },
    { "PASS", 2 }
};

static void OnSortCompareByTag(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    var tag1 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex1].Cells[e.Column.Index].Tag as string;
    var tag2 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex2].Cells[e.Column.Index].Tag as string;
    int result = sortOrder[tag1].CompareTo(sortOrder[tag2]);
    if (result == 0)
        result = Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(e.CellValue1 as string, e.CellValue2 as string);
    e.SortResult = result;
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    // Sort the selected column.
    dataGridView1.SortCompare += OnSortCompareByTag;
    dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn, direction);
    dataGridView1.SortCompare -= OnSortCompareByTag;

    // ...    
}
```