# Share code - Natural Sort sort for datagrid and list

Tags: c#, list, sorting, datagrid

I recently posted a question and received a perfect answer to natural sort a datagrid here  - [Natural Sort for Datgridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239449/natural-sort-for-datgridview). I then subsequently found a suitable solution to natural sort a list which was then added to a combobox.
There appears to be a lot of common code and wondered if there was a way to share the code. I have tried but one class uses objects and the other strings and try as I might I could not find a way to share the code.
The two classes and how they were called is shown below:
For Datagrid:

```
class NaturalSortComparer : System.Collections.IComparer
    {
        private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string[]> table;

        public NaturalSortComparer()
        { 
            table = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            table.Clear();
            table = null;
        }

        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {

                System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow1 = (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow)x;
                System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow2 = (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow)y;

                string xStr = DataGridViewRow1.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString().ToLower();
                string yStr = DataGridViewRow2.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString().ToLower();

            if (xStr == "")
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (xStr == yStr)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            string[] x1, y1;
            if (!table.TryGetValue(xStr, out x1))
            {
                x1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(xStr.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
                table.Add(xStr, x1);
            }
            if (!table.TryGetValue(yStr, out y1))
            {
                y1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(yStr.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
                table.Add(yStr, y1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < x1.Length && i < y1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (x1[i] != y1[i])
                {
                    return PartCompare(x1[i], y1[i]);
                }
            }
            if (y1.Length > x1.Length)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (x1.Length > y1.Length)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        private static int PartCompare(string left, string right)
        {
            int x, y;
            if (!int.TryParse(left, out x))
            {
                return left.CompareTo(right);
            }

            if (!int.TryParse(right, out y))
            {
                return left.CompareTo(right);
            }

            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
```

and was called:

```
dgvCategories.Sort(new NaturalSortComparer());
```

For lists:

```
public class NaturalSortComparerList : IComparer<string>, IDisposable
    {

        #region IComparer<string> Members

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IComparer<string> Members

        int IComparer<string>.Compare(string xwithcaps, string ywithcaps)
        {
            string x = xwithcaps.ToLower();
            string y = ywithcaps.ToLower();


            if (y == "")
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (x == y)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            string[] x1, y1;
            if (!table.TryGetValue(x, out x1))
            {
                x1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(x.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
                table.Add(x, x1);
            }
            if (!table.TryGetValue(y, out y1))
            {
                y1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(y.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
                table.Add(y, y1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < x1.Length && i < y1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (x1[i] != y1[i])
                {
                    return PartCompare(x1[i], y1[i]);
                }
            }
            if (y1.Length > x1.Length)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (x1.Length > y1.Length)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        private static int PartCompare(string left, string right)
        {
            int x, y;
            if (!int.TryParse(left, out x))
                return left.CompareTo(right);

            if (!int.TryParse(right, out y))
                return left.CompareTo(right);

            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }

        #endregion

        private Dictionary<string, string[]> table = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            table.Clear();
            table = null;
        }
    }
```

and called

```
cats.Sort(new NaturalSortComparerList());
```

where cats is a list containing entries that contain letters and numbers.

You will notice that the code in the two compare method varies to handle the string "". I need it to be at the top of the list or datagrid. For datagrid in NaturalSortComparer I need to use

```
if (xStr == "")
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

whereas to get the same results for lists in NaturalSortComparerList it reads

```
if (y == "")
        {
            return 0;
        }
```

I was hoping someone might be able to rationalise these two approaches and share some of the code. I again comment that I am relatively new to coding and have included code essentially as written in articles on this site. 
These two solutions work perfectly but it seems a bit clumsy to use both. Thanks

Comment: Sort method return negative number to indicate a < b, zero for a = b, and positive numbers for a > b.  So an empty string should return -1.

Comment: @jdweng I have tried to change it to -1 as you say but in both cases it   places the empty string in the middle of the list. It shouldn't make any difference but the empty string is always the first entry in the string or datagrid. It may be why it happens to work in my situation when I return 0 ???

Comment: There is nothing that checks if x = "".  I would do the check for x == y first, then check for x = ""

Comment: @jdweng I have tried as you suggest to place the statement with return of -1, in various places including after the x==y statement but still places empty string between numbers and letters.  I want it at the top of the list What seems to work is the code as written with the additional change as outlined in the addendum answer because of the way the two initial classes seemed to handle the empty strings differently. Not sure what would happen if there was more than one string as I will only ever have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share the code, first create a base class containing the functionality

```
public abstract class BaseComparer : IDisposable {
    private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string[]> table;

    public BaseComparer() {
        table = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        table.Clear();
        table = null;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y) {

        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow1 = x as System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow;
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow2 = y as System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow;

        string xStr = DataGridViewRow1 != null ? DataGridViewRow1.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString().ToLower() : x.ToString();
        string yStr = DataGridViewRow2 != null ? DataGridViewRow2.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString().ToLower() : y.ToString();

        if (xStr == "") {
            return 0;
        }

        if (xStr == yStr) {
            return 0;
        }
        string[] x1, y1;
        if (!table.TryGetValue(xStr, out x1)) {
            x1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(xStr.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
            table.Add(xStr, x1);
        }
        if (!table.TryGetValue(yStr, out y1)) {
            y1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(yStr.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
            table.Add(yStr, y1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < x1.Length && i < y1.Length; i++) {
            if (x1[i] != y1[i]) {
                return PartCompare(x1[i], y1[i]);
            }
        }
        if (y1.Length > x1.Length) {
            return 1;
        } else if (x1.Length > y1.Length) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static int PartCompare(string left, string right) {
        int x, y;
        if (!int.TryParse(left, out x)) {
           return left.CompareTo(right);
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(right, out y)) {
            return left.CompareTo(right);
        }

        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

This is basically just your initial code copied and pasted with this bit added:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow1 = x as System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow;
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow2 = y as System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow;

string xStr = DataGridViewRow1 != null ? DataGridViewRow1.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString().ToLower() : x.ToString();
string yStr = DataGridViewRow2 != null ? DataGridViewRow2.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString().ToLower() : y.ToString();
```

The purpose of the above is to identify whether the code is looking at a `DataGridViewRow` or a `String` which is a bit clumsy, but it should solve your problem and provide you with common core code.

The implementation of the two comparers is then straight forward as you inherit from your base class to share the functionality, so you end up with:

```
public class NaturalSortComparer : BaseComparer, System.Collections.IComparer {

}
```

and

```
public class NaturalSortComparerList : BaseComparer, IComparer<string> {
    public int Compare(string x, string y) {
        return base.Compare(x,y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary, did the job with a few tweaks which I have added as an another answer to this question as it seems to present code better than in comments.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly an answer but some tweaks to that given above to make it work in my situation. The initial two classes for some reason handled empty strings differently, so I have had to change a part of the comparer method in the BaseComparer class to read

```
if (xStr == ""|yStr=="")
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

There has been some discussion in comments about this not being the correct way to deal with empty strings. Not sure why but it seems to work, and if not included places the empty string between the entries that start with numbers and those with letters.
The other tweak is in the compare method of the NaturalSortComparerList class to read

```
public int Compare(string xWithCaps, string yWithCaps)
        {
            string x = xWithCaps.ToLower();
            string y = yWithCaps.ToLower();

            return base.Compare(x, y);
        }
```

This was changed to handle lower case entries correctly, because as originally written, "test5" would be placed above "Test1"